# why __dir__() doesn't work for module in python?

Tags: python

test_module.py:

```
def __dir__():
    return ['test']
```

my_module.py:

```
import test_module
print dir(test_module)
```

The result I expected should be `['test']`,
but actually, the result is:

```
['__builtins__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
```

why the `__dir__()` customerized by myself doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know what are you trying to achieve, but this may help: you can place any object into `sys.modules`, not only module type instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you need to limit what is listed for a module? `dir()` is a debugging tool, mostly.

Magic methods are normally looked up on the *type* of the object, so for instances, `dir()` looks for `type(instance).__dir__`. Your function is not on the `module` type, but on the module instance instead. You cannot extend the `module` type, however, so you cannot give modules a custom `__dir__` method.

If you wanted to limit what `from yourmodule import *` imports, then use `__all__` instead; it is expected to be a list, not a function. See the [`import` statement documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I note that, "f the object has a method named __dir__(), this method will be called and must return the list of attributes." from the manual, So, i just want to have a try.

Comment: Also, as you mentioned, if i define the __dir__() on an type, instead of a instance, it indeed works. An example is defining the __dir__() on an class, and call dir() to the instance of this class

Comment: From the [datamodel documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes): *For new-style classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in the object’s instance dictionary.*. A module is a built-in type, and a new-style class as far as that rule is concerned.

Comment: Or, more specifically, `module` objects are not old-style instance objects (which is what the [`dir()` C implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0012d4f0ca59/Objects/object.c#l1908) tests for; for modules, it then falls back to a [dedicated helper function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0012d4f0ca59/Objects/object.c#l1829), but only because the module type itself doesn't implement a `__dir__` special method.

Comment: thanks, will do that. No time today, will continue to think about your comments about this question.